# Execution of simulation of scripts in ns2

Tags: tcl, ns2

i have installed ns2 and tcl on my desktop (fedora).When i try to run a simulation on nam1.14 it shows "could'nt execute ns :no such file or directory".When i try to run the tcl script it shows "bash:ns: command not found".Why is this happening? i have installed ns-allinone-2.34 as per instructions.Plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that either the program isn't called `ns` (perhaps it's `ns2`?) or it isn't on your PATH environment variable. Deal with the former by checking *exactly* what it is called, and deal with the latter by finding out exactly where it is installed and looking to see if that directory is present on the PATH.